# Randomly select from array then assign selection to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object, random

I have a function that randomly selects a monster from an object.  Here's the function:

```
var travel = function(direction) {
        var newRoom = rooms[currentRoom.paths[direction]];
        if (!newRoom) {
            $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();
        }
        else {
            currentRoom = newRoom;
            $("<p>You are now in the " + currentRoom.name + " Room.</p>").properDisplay();
                if (currentRoom.hasMonsters) {
                    function pickRand() {
                        var monsterArray = Object.keys(monsters);   
                        var randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * monsterArray.length);
                        return $("<p>Holy Crap!  There's a " + monsterArray[randomKey] + " in here!</p>").properDisplay();  
                    }
                    pickRand();

                }
        }
    };
```

Here's the object:

```
var monsters = {
    zombie:  {
        hitPoints: 10,
        loot: "magic knife"
    },
    skeleton: {
        hitPoints: 15,
        loot: "magic shield"
    },
    ghoul:  {
        hitPoints: 12,
        loot: "magic helm"
    }
};
```

It's set up to randomly select "Zombie", "Skeleton", or "Ghoul."  Everything works fine.  How do I take whatever was randomly selected and save it to a variable?

I've tried a couple things like:

`var beast = pickRand();`

and

`var beast = monsterArray;`

But no luck.  What am I missing?

Comment: What does `properDisplay` return?

Comment: it adds some CSS and prepends some text in the game.  It's more cosmetic than anything.

Comment: Your `pickRand` function will be returning the return value of `properDisplay`. Why not just `return monsterArray[randomKey]`

Comment: If I do a return, how do I call it later?  Sorry, still trying to learn JS.  What I'm trying to do is assign the random value to a variable so I can use it later when you decide to fight the monster.  I want to be able to call whichever monster was randomly generated by name.  (zombie, ghoul, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're returning the return value of the `properDisplay` function.

If you used an array of monsters rather than a map you could store all of the monster information when you select a random one:

```
var monsters = [
    {
        name: 'zombie',
        hitPoints: 10,
        loot: "magic knife"
    },
    {
        name: 'skeleton',
        hitPoints: 15,
        loot: "magic shield"
    },
    {
        name: 'ghoul',
        hitPoints: 12,
        loot: "magic helm"
    }
];

function pickRand(arr) {
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    return arr[index];
}

var monster = pickRand(monsters);
```

Now that you have your monster you could display it:

```
$("<p>Holy Crap!  There's a " + monster.name + " in here!</p>").properDisplay();
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/louisbros/3cu9spfd/

Comment: Here is the fiddle I have @louisbros.  https://jsfiddle.net/eut1h5m7/  When I call the variable, it says [object object].  The only thing I can think is I placed the variable incorrectly?  The monster is called when you "go east" at the beginning of the game.

Comment: my bad.  I missed the display of `monster.name`.  Thanks @louisbros.  All set!

Comment: Is there any way to have the variable remember the same randomly selected monster for a period of time?  ie.  it randomly selects Zombie - how do I have it remember Zombie until I want it to randomly generate another monster?  Does that make sense? 

I get that everytime the function is called, it'll randomly generate again.  I need it to temporarily remember it's selection.

Comment: Yes you can keep the value each time by giving the `monster` variable a greater scope. For example, declare the variable outside the function and set it inside the function.

Comment: OK, I understand declaring outside the function.  You do that in your example.  I'm vague on "set it inside the function"  I did this: 
  
  `function pickRand(arr) {
   var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * monsters.length);
   return arr[index];
   var monster = pickRand(monsters);
  };
  
  var monster = pickRand(monsters);`

But no luck.  I'm sure it's the inside the function part I'm messing up.

Comment: What I meant was, declare the `monster` variable at the top `var monster;` then set the value in your travel function `monster = pickRand(monsters);`. Now the current selection is available outside your travel function.

Answer (score 0):

`var beast = pickRand();` should totally work. You just need to assign the variable right when you call it?

```
var travel = function(direction) {
        var newRoom = rooms[currentRoom.paths[direction]];
        if (!newRoom) {
            $("<p>You can't go that way.</p>").properDisplay();
        }
        else {
            currentRoom = newRoom;
            $("<p>You are now in the " + currentRoom.name + " Room.</p>").properDisplay();
                if (currentRoom.hasMonsters) {
                    function pickRand() {
                        var monsterArray = Object.keys(monsters);   
                        var randomKey = Math.floor(Math.random() * monsterArray.length);
                        return $("<p>Holy Crap!  There's a " + monsterArray[randomKey] + " in here!</p>").properDisplay();  
                    }
                    var beast = pickRand();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here's why I thought it didn't work.  I used that and just to see if it would call correctly, I added `alert(beast);` and it outputs `objectObject`.  I'm guessing that means it's calling the object incorrectly...

Comment: maybe try `alert(beast[0])`? You may need to look at the first item in that object